# php ahref link on certain mysql table results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database which has a shift pattern rota table in it that displays on a web page. The table that stores these shifts has fields of id and each dayname of the week with the shift value being a varchar field value and this is because 5 days of the week it has a numeric shift value i.e 123,456,789 and the other 2 days it has a text 'rest' value.  The 2 'rest' in the week vary from one week to the next.

This then results in being displayed in a table on the webpage but what I would like to do is have a ahref clickable link on the numeric shift values that will then forward to a page showing the full shift information but dont want to have a clickable link for the 'rest' of each one.

example of table is

```
id - auto incrememt numeric
saturday - varchar
sunday - varchar
monday - varchar
tuesday - varchar
ect ect for the rest of the week
```

How would i be able to achieve this please - I am fairly new to php so any help you can give will be appreciated and please can you try not to blind me with science lol.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You could add an `if` statement to check if the shift value is "rest", and only output the link if it isn't. If that doesn't work, add the code you have so we can have a look.

Comment: I cannot understand why you need fields for each day of the week's name. Why just a single field in which you store a single day's name.

Comment: Here is my code as it stands at the moment.
try{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM r128_rota";   
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->rowCount() > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch()){
        
            echo "<tr'>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sat'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['sun'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['mon'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['tue'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";            
        }
        echo "</table>";

Comment: reason i have seperate fields for the day of week is as i said i am new to php so have done it the best way i currently know how to obviously as i become more educated with it then i may find a better way of doing both the mysql and php.

Answer (score 0):

Your table seems to hold a weeks worth of shifts. It would probably be much simpler for you if each row held only a single shift.

I would suggest that your table has a `shift_id` field and a `day_of_week` field, with values 1 through 5 being Monday through Friday and anything else being a special value.

Then, in your PHP, you only need to create `HREF` for `day_of_Week` between 1 and 5.

Try coding that & if you are still stuck, start a new question with your code and your tables. For the tables give us the output of both

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <table name>;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM <table name>LIMIT 10;
```

That will give us both the table layout and sample data (with `LIMIT 10` so that we get ore than a week's worth, but not too much).

Comment: yeah table actually holds what could be upto 6months worth of shifts which is how the rota works and each person has a unique pay number so depending on that would depend where on the rota they would be and they wish to be able to see the whole rota so they can plan which shifts they wish to change.  hope that makes sense

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think that you are quite new to database design (no offence intended).  You ought to think carefully about your database. Using [MySql WOrkbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) should help.It sounds like you need a table for each shift, with an indication of the day of the week (plus shift # if there are 2 or 3 per day). Then a table per employee, with one row for each shift worked.

Comment: yeah i am new to it hence why it is probably at this stage no where as good as it could or should be but obviously as i learn better ways i can update the mysql or php. yeah i basically need it to have each day of the week and then that shows a shift number (123,456) or rest along with the persons unique id which they have which is a numeric value they get assigned. there is only one shift per day.

Comment: I do think that you need to learn more about databases. Google for some tutorials, or buy something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-MySQL-Apache/dp/0672335433/).  Good luck. ***Do not*** start coding until you have your database schema correct. And learn about [PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo) for your PHP database access